# Pass data from Array to XML and save to variable

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I have an array `$data = array ( 'name' => 'makis', 'pw' => 'sovara')` and i need to fill in an XML file using those values and then save that XML into a temporary variable.
For example the XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
                <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0
                epp-1.0.xsd">
                <command>
                <login>
                <clID>['name']</clID>
                <pw>['pw']</pw>
                <options>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <lang>en</lang>
                </options>
                <svcs>
                <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:host-1.0</objURI>
                <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:contact-1.0</objURI>
                <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0</objURI>
                </svcs>
                </login>
                <clTRID>nick-12345</clTRID>
                </command>
                </epp>
```

How can i do that in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('path/to/file');

// $xml is object that represents <epp> root node
$xml->command->login->clID = $data['name'];
$xml->command->login->pw = $data['pw'];

$xml->asXML('new/file/path'); // save to new file
```